# Easy Way to Recursively Delete Directories in IsolatedStorage on WP7 & 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage, directory

In IsolatedStorage you have to delete all the folders and files inside a directory before you can delete the directory itself in IsolatedStorage.

Normally If I'm deleting a directory in IsolatedStorage which has some files inside I would get the list of directories, then use a `foreach` statement and check if each of those has files then use another `foreach` statement to delete each of the files inside those directories.

However I have a much more complicated FileSystem going on in `IsolatedStorage` which looks a bit like this:

`Several Main directories` which contain `Several sub-directories` these `sub-directories`
contain another `1-100 additional sub-directories` which contain about `3-5 files`

At the moment the only technique I know of (using `foreach` statements and many `IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication().GetDirectoryNames()`) is hardly what you would call efficient.

Is there an easier/easy way of checking for recursively deleting directories and their files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the API does not support recursive deletions, so you wlll have to do it yourself. Like e.g.

```
public static void DeleteDirectoryRecursively(this IsolatedStorageFile storageFile, String dirName)
{
    String pattern = dirName + @"\*";
    String[] files = storageFile.GetFileNames(pattern);
    foreach (var fName in files)
    {
        storageFile.DeleteFile(Path.Combine(dirName, fName));
    }
    String[] dirs = storageFile.GetDirectoryNames(pattern);
    foreach (var dName in dirs)
    {
        DeleteDirectoryRecursively(storageFile, Path.Combine(dirName, dName));
    }
    storageFile.DeleteDirectory(dirName);
}
```

Comment: That's sort of the thing I was using before, but it still doesn't solve the issue of deleting directories inside directories inside directories?

Comment: @user2696648 uhm ... yes it does. it deletes them recursively by calling `DeleteDirectoryRecursively` on the subdirectories it finds.

Comment: thanks, I set `String dirName = ""` in the params as I wanted to delete everything.

Answer (score 0):

The user store has a method Clear() that cleans the whole thing

```
using (var userStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    userStore.Clear();
}
```

Keep in mind this deletes EVERYTHING, even configurations

Comment: Yeah I know about that, I want to be able to delete specific directories which have several sub directories which contain more directories and more files

Comment: Then recursivity it is... And that you already have it, don't you?

Comment: IsolatedStorageFile has no Clear() method, it has a Remove() method. Which does the same thing.